# Date conversion in R

Tags: r

I have a date column in the below format. I'm trying to extract day of the week. But it returns NA's.

```
df = data.frame(date=c("05-SEP-18", "10-SEP-18", "22-SEP-18"))
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ date: Factor w/ 3 levels "05-SEP-18","10-SEP-18",..: 1 2 3
df$day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$date, '%d-%M-%Y'))
head(df)
   date  day 
1 05-SEP-18 <NA>
2 10-SEP-18 <NA>
3 22-SEP-18 <NA>
```

I converted the factors to char. It still returns NA's

```
df$date <- as.character(df$date)
df$day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$date, '%d-%M-%Y'))
head(df)
date  day 1 05-SEP-18 <NA> 2 10-SEP-18 <NA> 3 22-SEP-18 <NA>
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Pretty sure that `%Y` is a *four* digit year. You have only two digits.

Comment: And `%M` is for numeric month. `%b` is abbreviated month.

Answer (score 0):

Try `as.Date(df$date, '%d-%b-%y')`. `%y%` is two digit year.
`%b%` is character abbreviated month.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/amp/

Answer (score 0):

Try this with package lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
df = data.frame(date = c("05-SEP-18", "10-SEP-18", "22-SEP-18"))
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
#define timezone
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d-%b-%y")
wd <- weekdays(df$date)
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above `lubridate` is an easy solution to parse the date and then use  `tidyverse` to pipe together functions and create new columns:

```
  df %>% 
    mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>% 
    mutate(day  = weekdays(date))

        date       day
1 2018-09-05 Wednesday
2 2018-09-10    Monday
3 2018-09-22  Saturday
```

so while you can specify the date format manually, using functions such as `dmy` in `lubridate` simplifies this when the date is in a somewhat standard format.